# Changing first day of week in Team Foundation Server 2012 update 1

Tags: tfs, settings, administration

I want to change first day of week in **TFS 2012 update 1** and use it in **Iterations** settings, but I can't find any place to do it.
Is there any place to change that?

I change First day of week in **Region and Language** but it doesn't affect on TFS date picker.
And also I want to change the weekend because we use a different calendar in our country.

Comment: The UI should honour whatever your local computer is set to.

Comment: @MrHinsh no, it doesn't.

Comment: Did you change the date setting on a client, or the TFS server box?

Comment: @aclear16 yes, I changed it on both of them.

Comment: The only thing sent to the server is the locale name, not anything you customized, so unless you can find a locale with that particular day of the week first you're probably out of luck.  Only IE pays attention to the computers locale to my knowledge, others have to be changed in their settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to change the days off, so you will need to customize the process template, In the common process config settings you can change the weekend days.

See this link:

[How to change the default days off](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFSvnext/thread/e301237d-4ab5-4c3e-8925-c93a18c5214a)

**Updated on Jun, 31, 2013**

---

Just add the first language is Arabic in the browser settings and it will work but of course the calendar will be in Arabic, see the image:

[image]

Comment: I changed `<weekends>` by this method, but is there anyway to change the first day of week in Sprint DatePicker?